# Load page in div, go to top of that div

Tags: javascript, html

I have:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function arata(temp) { 
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            req.open("GET", temp, false); 
            req.send(null); 
            var page = req.responseText; 
            document.getElementById("produs").innerHTML = page; 
                      } 
</script>
```

and:

```
<a href="#produs" onclick="arata('facturaies_vezi.php?nrfacties=<?=$row[nrfacties];?>#produs'); return true;"  id="<?=$nrcrt;?>">See details</a>
```

and:

```
<div id="produs"></div>
```

So, when the link is clicked, the page loads in to div.
How can I do to align the top of div to the top of the viewpoint? I mean... something like using an #anchor.

Comment: I did, but for any link (is a list of links) the page scrolls randomly.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.getElementById('produs').scrollIntoView();
```

See here for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollIntoView

Comment: Did that before posting here, too. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with an anchor, you can add one `<a name="produs"></a>` above the div and it should work if you do not `return false` on the `click` event.

Comment: Did that before posting here.

Comment: have you also tried using `window.location.hash`? Do you get the hash in the address bar? is the div (`<div id="produs"></div>`) positioned absolute/fixed?